# Is "Made heavy use of [X] principles." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> Developed a mobile app that performs [something]. Made heavy use of
>   [X] principles.

Is the use of *"made heavy use of [X] principles"* grammatically correct? Can one *make heavy use of some principles*? What I mean is that I developed a mobile app that performs [something] and I also applied [X] principles (e.g. OOP principles) to the implementation of the app.

Answer (score 1):

"To make heavy use of (something)" is fine.

However, it is not OK to say that you **used** principles, since principles are abstract notions.

You can **base** (something) **on** principles, or you can **follow** principles, or **respect** principles.

Or you can make (heavy) use of technologies, tools, knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

I would never ever say 'make heavy use of'.

There are some collocations you could try playing around: ***make great use of*** or ***heavily*** ***depend on*** or ***stick to/adhere to/stand by some principles***.

Comment: By the way, could I just use "Developed a mobile app that performs [something]. Applied [X] principles."?

Comment: Principle applied were the following: encapsulation, inheritance, etc.

Comment: Why wouldn't you say "make heavy use of"?  It isn't useful to say "I would never do this"  unless you say why.  ["Make heavy use of" is a perfectly valid phrasing, if not the most common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+heavy+use+of%2Cmake+*+use+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000)  Here's an example in live usage:  [**Syrian army source: rebels make heavy use of TOW missiles**](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-syria-arms-idUSKBN0TE1KJ20151125)

Comment: Really? That's good to know. Seriously have never heard/came across that one.

Comment: Google's ngram viewer is awesome! Thank you @stangdon